# How to find the AMI names of all the EC2 instances in my account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, instance, amazon-ami

Using aws ec2 describe-images only gives the AMI IDs and other details of the EC2 instances. I need the AMI names. Is there any way to display or export the AMI names of all the EC2 Instances in an AWS account.

Comment: Are you saying: "For each Amazon EC2 instance running in my account, find the AMIs that were used to launch each of the instances and display the name of the AMI?" If so, you would first need to `describe-instances` and then for each instance you would need to `describe-image`. I think the 'name' is stored in the Name tag (but it depends on what you consider to be the 'name' of the AMI).

Answer (score 0):

describe-images cli has some filtering options. We then need to query the results.

You could do something like below.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=state, Values=available" --query 'Images[*].[Name]' --ouput text
```

This will get all "available" image names in the corresponding region. You may use different filtering options.

Another example:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=root-device-type, Values=ebs" --query 'Images[*].[Name]' --ouput text
```

Comment: Be careful -- this could return a huge number of images since it is not filtering to `owner=self`.